# jQuery mobile, Listview with a checkbox

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

Got a listview that looks like this:
http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.3.0/docs/examples/swipe/swipe-list.html#demo-page

It contains two clickable areas.

I've search around for an example where they have checkbox in the listview, good example was this one: [jsfiddle.net/yakirmanor/d8KNF/](http://jsfiddle.net/yakirmanor/d8KNF/)

But I dont whant to have a big "label for" that takes all the area. I whant that my text to be a link.
But it seems to be hard, i've been mixing around for a solution but it ends up with that the checkbox takes a own line.
I've tried to make a `<div>` and have `float="left"` but it doesn't really look as I want.

In my first example link I have 2 areas, the one to the right could be a checkbox. But it seems like it need to be a link to get that area.

Is there any good solution? Or do I need to make it a own line?

All this will be for a inbox view. And my checkbox on left or right side will be a selection for what message to be deleted.

Comment: show us the result you have reached.

Comment: It seems to be a CSS-problem because you are talking about style and how you want it to be displayed visually. Is that correct? Can you please show us a code snippet?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for late answear!

I have the checkbox on another line now. But actually I want it next to my message. As they usally are on inboxes for devices when you selecting items for delete.

```
        <div data-role="content">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="false" data-icon="false" data-split-icon="delete" data-filter="true">
            <li data-role="list-divider">Details</li>
            @foreach (var message in Model.MessageList)
            {
                <li data-role="fieldcontain"><a href="/Message/Detail?messageRef=@message.MessageRef">
                    <h3>@message.FromPersonName</h3>
                    <h2>@message.MessageHeader</h2>
                    <p>
                        My information about</p>
                </a>
                    <label style="border-top-width: 0px; margin-top: 0px; border-bottom-width: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px;
                        border-left-width: 0px; border-right-width: 0px;" data-corners="false">
                        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
                            <input id="@("cbx" + message.MessageRef)" class="markedForDelete" name="CheckboxToDelete" type="checkbox"
                               value=@message.MessageRef />
                        </fieldset>
                    </label>
                </li>
            }
        </ul>
    </div>
```

And as I showed in my second exampel link in my first message. There is a solution. But they have all the message text as a "label for". I want to seperate it, the message would be a link as it is in my example.